# Ubuntu 14- no internet connections at all

Tags: networking, internet

I'm booting Ubuntu in WMware Workstation while using Win7, my laptop has internet connection in windows, but when I go to Ubuntu, it does not reckognize any connections. I searched the answers online, and tried connecting via cable and updating drivers, but it still doesn't reckognize any connections even with cable, and I can't update now. How do I fix this? In the network menu it also says Ethernet network disconnected. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

you can use nat for network in vmware and then ubuntu can connect to network with dhcp if you now use bridge you must use network manager from top panel in ubuntu and add lan with specify ip address also i sugested you in vmware use nat network this is easy way

Comment: I don't really understand what should I do. Should I use the bridge connection or? It's using nat now, and it doesn't work.

Comment: ok open terminal with ctrl+alt+t and  try sudo  ifup eth0

Comment: It says- Ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0

Comment: I fixed it, just switched to Bridge connection instead of NAT, and it's working. Thanks for your assistance!